# SQL, Converting Cyrillic to Latin or Latin to Cyrillic

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Have huge data in Oracle DB. To search datas we create WPF application.
When user type symbol like A%, query should seacrh both, in Latin and in Cyrillic word. Symbols already recorded in Cyrillic in DB. Column type varchar2(20byte) and can not be changed type.
In query I tried,

```
Select *
from Table1
where symbol=N'A'; // A - Latin symbol
```

but no result. I in query I put Cyrillic symbol there is result.

How to od it?

Comment: Does every cyrillic glyph have an _unambiguous_ latin counterpart?

Comment: not all, A, O, E,C, K and some more

Comment: And do you restrict "searchable" characters to those? Or what can users enter in general? Just single chars?

Comment: they will enter like A54186, K51786, AK574178, CC015687, AKC962896 or AKCOE etc.

Comment: Ok, in such cases you need to get hits on for example "A54186" as well as "А54186" (the cyrillic one), I see now.

Comment: I was just trying to understand what you are doing. And now I get it. "A" looks the same in cyrillic and latin, but they are actually different codepoints. Which the user doesn't really care about. For them, an "A" is supposed to be an "A". So, they do not want to switch input encoding for that. That would be really inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a limited number of characters then you can use [`TRANSLATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRANSLATE.html) to substitute the Cyrillic character(s) to their ASCII equivalent(s):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Table1
WHERE  TRANSLATE(symbol, UNISTR('\0410'), 'A') = 'A';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (symbol VARCHAR2(10));
INSERT INTO table1 (symbol) VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO table1 (symbol) VALUES (UNISTR('\0410'));
```

Outputs:

| SYMBOL |
| --- |
| A |
| А |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h2T1BNm_)